# Merge tags 'sleep-mode' and 'standby'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-cleanup

While updating our tag wikis, I came on the tag [sleep-mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sleep-mode) (x26). Wondering about that term, I checked and found [standby](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standby) (x13). Going by the questions, they are at least related -- and I'd even go so far as naming them "synonym". As `standby` already has a good tag wiki, and to me should be the "main tag" even regardless of this fact, I'd suggest to merge the two and make `sleep-mode` a synonym to `standby`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merged!